# CPaneFrameWnd without WS_CAPTION cannot support different DPIs in multiple monitors (Windows10)?

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am using MFC feature pack to develop my own dockable pane. 
In pane's floating state, I don't use `WS_CAPTION` style due to design requirement when creating `CPaneFrameWnd`. Everything runs well until moving the floating `CPaneFrameWnd` from one monitor to another. These 2 monitors are set in different DPIs. The issue is that `CPaneFrameWnd` cannot follow my mouse position when crossing the monitor edge. There is a 100+ pixels gap between them depending on DPI settings.

I use `MonitorFromWindow` in `OnMouseMove` to query the monitor handler, and find that monitor handler won't change when my mouse and `CPaneFrameWnd` already appear in the other monitor. At the same time, `GetCursorPos` still returns the position in initial monitor as well. I need to keep moving, then the monitor handler and mouse position are changed to the new one.

If `CPaneFrameWnd` is created with `WS_CAPTION` style, then there is no such issue. I think there is a coordinate switch when crossing the monitors with different DPIs with `WS_CAPTION` enabled. Does anyone know how is it done so that I can use it without `WS_CAPTION` style ? Or why MFC doesn't do such switch without `WS_CAPTION` style ?

I add below code in the MFC sample application and build with "High DPI Aware" instead of "Per Monitor High DPI Aware". The pMiniFrameCaption can be moved from one monitor to another smoothly, but pMiniFrameNoCaption will "jump".

```
CPaneFrameWnd* pMiniFrameCaption = new CPaneFrameWnd();

if (pMiniFrameCaption != NULL)
{
    CRect rect;
    rect.SetRect(CPoint(200, 200), CPoint(400, 400));
    if (!pMiniFrameCaption->Create(L"CPaneFrameWnd", WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION, rect, this))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create miniframe");
        delete pMiniFrameCaption;
        return NULL;
    }

    pMiniFrameCaption->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

CPaneFrameWnd* pMiniFrameNoCaption = new CPaneFrameWnd();

if (pMiniFrameNoCaption != NULL)
{
    CRect rect;
    rect.SetRect(CPoint(0, 0), CPoint(200, 200));

    if (!pMiniFrameNoCaption->Create(L"CPaneFrameWnd", WS_POPUP, rect, this))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create miniframe");
        delete pMiniFrameNoCaption;
        return NULL;
    }

    pMiniFrameNoCaption->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is the application settings "DPI aware" or "DPI per monitor aware"?

Comment: The app is "High DPI Aware", and we cannot set it as "DPI per monitor aware". Per my understanding, if using per monitor, we need to scale the app dialogs and controls by ourselves, which will be a great great effort for the app.